# How do you make the tools of the toolstrip not disappear when stretched

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a web browser with VB.NET with Windows Forms, while testing i realised that when i resize the form the tools on the toolstrip disappear. I disabled the CanOverflow but that is still the problem

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what you're doing and what happens. I've never seen what you describe so, to be able to tell you how to prevent it, I have to see it happen first. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For example a browser has a back forward refresh button and a address bar. When i make the window smaller the tooltip overflows and the tools in the tooltip disappear

Comment: Please put your toolstrips in a ToolStripContainer1.TopToolStripPanel instead.